Exclude files from SonarQube coverage analysis in a plugin
I have a few files like navigation, intent and autogenerated files, that I want to exclude from SonarQube's coverage analysis. I want to put this in a gradle plugin so I can apply this to multiple modules. Is there a way to do this?
I have the 5.0.0.4638 version of SonarQube.
Ex for files: "/Navigation.", "/NavGraph.".
I think I need a class that implements the Plugin interface.
class SonarQubeExclusionPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        // TODO
    }
}

I saw somewhere an approach like this but I can't reach SonarQubeExtension class, even though I added SonarQube to the module.
class SonarQubeExclusionPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        project.afterEvaluate {
            configureSonarQubeExtension(project)
        }
    }

    private fun configureSonarQubeExtension(project: Project) {
        val intentFilesToExclude = listOf(
            "**/*Activity.*",
            "**/*Fragment.*"
            // Add more intent-related file patterns here if needed
        )

        project.extensions.configure(SonarQubeExtension::class.java) { extension ->
            extension.properties {
                it["sonar.coverage.exclusions"] = intentFilesToExclude.joinToString(",")
            }
        }
    }
}

